# Excel Date formatting replace "." with "/"

Tags: excel, date, formatting

I have entered the date in the excel as 19.04.2015 but now I want the "." in these dates to be replaced with "/", so that the output should be 19/04/2015

Does anyone know the formula for this?

Comment: Do you want to replace the value or would it be enough for you to use standard cell formatting?

Comment: I think standard cell formatting will work

Answer (score 1):

Tutorial to change the date [format](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e). The way you should do it is change the data type to date on fields with date then modify date display format.

Comment: I am unable to change it by word date formatting. It is not converting the date written in 14.06.2015 to 14-06-2015

Comment: isn't it due the american data format you have selected? Try to change the data format first to the European, then input the dates, the excel should treat them as dates, then change the dates into the proper format.

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1,** in **B1** enter:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2))
```

and apply the correct format to **B1**

[image]

Comment: Not exactly the same I did, I just selected the entire column, and added custom format.. Its so easy.. Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the cell format to Custom Format using `TT/MM/JJJJ`